# WPF DataGrid AutoGenerated columns, change header name

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, wpftoolkit

I recall in Silverlight the ability to place an Attribute on a given property in the Model for an alternate display name when auto generating columns on a data grid. Is this possible in WPF? I don't want to use the event handler to change the names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it...here is what I was referencing [DisplayAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute%28v=VS.95%29.aspx), however that does not appear valid in WPF, only SL. For WPF it can be done like this...keeping everything in XAML...

```
    <dg:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding DatabaseConnections, Mode=Default}">
        <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
            <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Display" Binding="{Binding DisplayName}"></dg:DataGridTextColumn>
        </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
    </dg:DataGrid>
```

...this allows you to change the `DisplayName` property to get displayed as "Display" in the header of the `DataGrid`.

Comment: Here the "AutoGenerateColumns" is disabled which contraddicts to the title of the question :/

Answer (score 2):

Check out: [How to: Customize Auto-Generated Columns in the DataGrid Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903950%28VS.95%29.aspx).

Comment: That is via handling the event, I don't want to do that and I recall in SL the ability to place an Attribute for a property in the Model to define the alternate text

Comment: This is how I did it, but that said, please post your solution so I can use it too if/when you find one.